# Difference between const ref and const pointer, c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I'd like to know what's the difference between const ref and const pointer in c++.
When I declare on something to be const ref, can I change it's VALUE?
or the const goes on the object?
Because I know that const pointer means you cannot change the POINTER but you can change the VALUE it points to.

for example:

```
const char& a; // ?
const char* a; // pointer is const
```

Comment: Re-evaluate what you "know".  Test it.

Comment: `const char* a; // pointer is const` -- No, the referent is const.

Answer (score 5):

> Fred const& x;

It means x aliases a Fred object, but x can't be used to change that Fred object.

> Fred const* p;

Fred const* p means "p points to a constant Fred": the Fred object can't be changed via p.

> Fred* const p;

Fred* const p means "p is a const pointer to a Fred": you can't change the pointer p, but you can change the Fred object via p.

---

It's possible to combine the last to to get:

> Fred const* const p;

Fred const* const p means "p is a constant pointer to a constant Fred": you can't change the pointer p itself, nor can you change the Fred object via p.

For more on this visit this [link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Answer (score 2):

`const char* a; // pointer is const`

Wrong, this is a pointer to a constant. This:

`char* const a; // pointer is const`

is a constant pointer.

Comment: While your observation is correct, this doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to write these like this: `char const * a` vs. `char * const a`.

This allows you to read from right to left: `char const * a` is: `a` is a pointer to a constant `char`, and `char * const a` is: `a` is a constant pointer to a `char`. And if I read other code, I just remember that `const char* a = char const* a`.

To answer the other part of your question:
*When I declare on something to be const ref, can I change it's VALUE?*
People misuse the term const ref to actually mean reference to a constant (since a constant reference makes no sense). So, const ref `const char& a` means that you *cannot* change the value. But if you actually mean you want a constant reference, `char& const a` then you *can* change the value and the `const` part makes no difference.

For pointers, `const char* a` means you cannot change the value `a` points to. Compare this to `char* const a` which means you cannot change the pointer, but you can change the value `a` points to.